# How to do parallelism in splitter-aggregator in spring integration?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a rest call to do inside splitter and then aggregate. I planned to implement parallelism for this rest call. So i introduced task executor as per this [link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/120277-spring-integration-parallel-processing). Now parallelism works but sometimes it is working and sometimes not. Guessing the aggregator is not waiting for all the thread to finish. Not sure exactly the problem. Can you help me here.

```
    <int:enricher ipChann="som" opCahnnel="inputChannel" />

    <int:splitter ipchan="inputChannel" opChannel="opchannel" ref="customersplitter" /> 

    <int:channel id="opchannel" >
        <int:dispatcher task-executor="exec" />
    </int:channel>

    <task:executor id="exec" pool-size="4" queue-capacity="10"/>

    <int:enricher ipChannel="opchannel" opChannel="aggregatorChan"></int:enricher>

    <int:aggregator ipChann="aggregatorChan"  />
```

For simplicity i didnt expand enricher, but the flow are same.

Comment: Please, share your configuration and custom code. You should understand here that it is in parallel if there is enough thread in the pool. Otherwise all new tasks are waiting for the gap in the thread-pool-executor. Without aggregator code we can't help you anyway.

Comment: If you run with DEBUG logging, you should be able to figure out what's happening.